# Converting OpenStreetMaps PBF to geojson with geocoding

Tags: openstreetmap, geojson, geocoding, elasticsearch

I am able to convert PBF to geojson, but I lack the additional attributes like state, country, city, suburb, type of business etc which is offered by geocoding service like Nominatim.

The geojson just has a name and type:

```
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "osm_id": "519326004", "timestamp": "2014-10-29T19:46:31Z", "name": "Borgo Agnese", "type": "restaurant" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 16.6015512, 49.1915338 ] } }
```

But I need all these additional attributes:

```
[{"place_id":"4709238","licence":"Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http:\/\/www.openstreetmap.org\/copyright","osm_type":"node","osm_id":"519326004","boundingbox":["49.1914838","49.1915838","16.6015012","16.6016012"],"polygonpoints":[[16.6015512,49.1915838],[16.601586555339,49.191569155339],[16.6016012,49.1915338],[16.601586555339,49.191498444661],[16.6015512,49.1914838],[16.601515844661,49.191498444661],[16.6015012,49.1915338],[16.601515844661,49.191569155339]],"lat":"49.1915338","lon":"16.6015512","display_name":"Borgo Agnese, 43, Kopečná, Staré Brno, Brno, okres Brno-město, Jihomoravský kraj, Jihovýchod, 60200, Czech Republic","class":"amenity","type":"restaurant","importance":0.201,"icon":"http:\/\/nominatim.openstreetmap.org\/images\/mapicons\/food_restaurant.p.20.png","address":{"restaurant":"Borgo Agnese","house_number":"43","road":"Kopečná","suburb":"Staré Brno","city":"Brno","county":"okres Brno-město","state":"Jihovýchod","postcode":"60200","country":"Czech Republic","country_code":"cz"}}]
```

I can reverse geocode every entry I have in my geojson created from PBF file but that seems cumbersome to me.

Just to note: I have tried [Pelias openstreetmap utilities](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pelias-openstreetmap) to upload PBF to Elasticsearch, but the quality of information is not sufficient for me.

Is there any proper way how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelias gets boundaries from external source (or form OSM but loaded via separate query) and join points with boundaries within ElasticSearch.

Try this https://github.com/kiselev-dv/gazetteer/tree/develop/Gazetteer
It uses pretty similar scheme (with some additions) as Pelias.

Run gazetteer.jar from releases with:

```
bzcat CH.osm.bz | java -jar gazetteer.jar split - none
java -Xmx4g -jar gazetteer.jar slice
java -Xmx4g -jar gazetteer.jar join --handlers out-gazetteer cz.json.gz
```

And you'll get cz.json.gz with json with all data you need.

And if I don't mind, you have conscription numbers in Czech, so notice that you'll get two lines for each building one with regular address, and another one addressed via conscription number.